# find all $x \in S_5$ such that $x^3 = (12)$

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

So I have to find all $x \in S_5$ such that $x^3 = (12)$. For example, one solution would be $(12)$ itself, because its order is $2$. How can I find all of the solutions though? Is it just trial and error?

(also, the multiplication is defined from left to right, just fyi)

Comment: Well, $\;x^3=(12)\implies x^6=(x^3)^2=(12)^2=1\implies o(x)\;$ is a divisor of $\;6\;$ , so you already eliminate lots of elements of $\;S_5\;$ ...

Comment: ok, makes sense. still, I need to find the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$o(x)$ is a divisor of $6$ means $o(x)=1,2,3$ 0r $6$. $o(x)=1,3$ are automatically excluded. For $o(x)=2$, $x=(12)$ is the only solution. For $x=6$, $x=(12)(abc)$ is a solution, where $a,b,c\in \{3,4,5\}$.